# Implements ads in libgdx game correctly

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx, admob

I KNOW ITS LONG BUT I NEED HELP PLEASE.

I've been working (and struggling) with this libgdx game for the past month now and everything worked out fine but when I added interstitial ad in it then it became unexpectedly slow and the game glitches a lot..it works fine if i remove the code with the ads

How my game works is it goes from MenuState>>PlayState>>GameOverState>>PlayState>>GameOverState and so on..(all of the code are given below)

I've got a couple questions
(a) How do I get my game to work smoothly?
(b) Is there any way to show ads only in GameOverState?(I tried introducing a boolean and a 'if' statement on the ad but failed)
(c)How do i dispose my assets more effeciently?(They don't dispose if the classes are called too fast repeatedly)

If you require any more information about it, do let me know and I would be happy to do so..

States:

Main libgdx class:GrumpyDemo

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
import com.mygdx.game.States.AdCloseState;
import com.mygdx.game.States.GameOverState;
import com.mygdx.game.States.GameStateManager;
import com.mygdx.game.States.MenuState;

public class GrumpyDemo extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public static final int WIDTH = 480;
    public static final int HEIGHT= 800;

public static final String TITLE = "Flappy Bird";
private GameStateManager gsm;
public static long AdStart = 0;
public AdController adController;


private SpriteBatch batch;

public GrumpyDemo(AdController adController){
    this.adController = adController;
}


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gsm = new GameStateManager();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
    AdStart = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    adController.showBannerAds();
}

@Override
public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gsm.render(batch);
    if (TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(AdStart)> 30000){
        adController.showInterstitialAds(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gsm.pop();
                gsm.push(new AdCloseState(gsm));
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();



}
}
```

My abstract class: State

```
 package com.mygdx.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

/**
 * Created by Kronos on 28-01-2017.
 */

public abstract class State {

    protected OrthographicCamera cam;
    protected Vector3 mouse;
    protected GameStateManager gsm;

    protected State(GameStateManager gsm){
        this.gsm = gsm;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        mouse = new Vector3();


    }

    protected abstract void handleInput();
    public abstract void update(float dt);
    public abstract void render(SpriteBatch sb);
    public abstract void dispose();
```

MenuState:

```
 private Texture background;
private Texture playBtn;
private Music music;

public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, GrumpyDemo.WIDTH / 2, GrumpyDemo.HEIGHT / 2);
    background = new Texture("bg.png");
    playBtn = new Texture("playbtn.png");
    music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("mainmusic.mp3"));
    music.setVolume(0.8f);
    music.play();

}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));

    }


}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();

}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background, 0, 0);
    sb.draw(playBtn, cam.position.x - playBtn.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y);
    sb.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    background.dispose();
    playBtn.dispose();
    music.dispose();
    System.out.println("Menu State Disposed");
}
```

PlayState:

```
package com.mygdx.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
import com.mygdx.game.GrumpyDemo;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Bird;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Tube;

/**
 * Created by Kronos on 28-01-2017.
 */

public class PlayState extends State {
    private static final int TUBE_SPACING = 75;
    private static final int TUBE_COUNT = 4;


    private Bird bird;
    private Texture actualGamebg;
    private Tube tube ;
    private Texture ground;
    private Vector2 groundPos1,groundPos2;
    private static final int HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT = -30;
    private Array<Tube> tubes;
    private int k;
    long startTime=0;
    private Music mainMusic;
    private Music scoreIncrease;
    private Music wingFlap;
    public BitmapFont font24;
    public String SCORE;
    public int l;
    public long gameOverStart=0;






    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        bird = new Bird(0,300);
        actualGamebg = new Texture("bg.png");
        cam.setToOrtho(false, GrumpyDemo.WIDTH/2,GrumpyDemo.HEIGHT/2);

        tubes =new Array<Tube>();
        ground = new Texture("ground.png");
        mainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("mainmusic.mp3"));
        scoreIncrease = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("smw_coin.ogg"));
        wingFlap = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("sfx_wing.ogg"));

        font24= new BitmapFont();
        SCORE = new String();
        fontGenerator();
        groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x -cam.viewportWidth/2, HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
        groundPos2 = new Vector2((cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth/2) + ground.getWidth(),HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
        startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        gameOverStart = TimeUtils.millis();

        for(int i=1 ; i<=TUBE_COUNT; i++)
        {

            tubes.add(new Tube(i* (TUBE_SPACING + Tube.TUBE_WIDTH)));
        }
        mainMusic.play();
        mainMusic.setVolume(0.8f);
        mainMusic.setLooping(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
            bird.jump();
        wingFlap.setLooping(false);
        wingFlap.play();
        wingFlap.setVolume(0.1f);
    }




    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();

        updateGround();

        bird.update(dt);
        if (TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(startTime) > 1400000000)
        {
            Score();
            startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }



        SCORE = String.valueOf(k);





        for(int i =0 ; i< tubes.size;i++)
        {
            Tube tube= tubes.get(i);

            if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2) > tube.getPosTopTube().x + tube.getTopTube().getWidth())
            {
                tube.reposition(tube.getPosTopTube().x + ((Tube.TUBE_WIDTH + TUBE_SPACING) *TUBE_COUNT));
            }
            if(tube.collides(bird.getBounds()))
            {

                    cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x;
                    mainMusic.stop();

                    gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
                    l = k;

            }

            else
                cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x +80;

        }
        if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight()){

            gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
           mainMusic.stop();

            l = k;

        }




        cam.update();

    }



    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(actualGamebg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
        sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x , bird.getPosition().y);
        for(Tube tube: tubes) {

            sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
            sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBottomTube().x, tube.getPosBottomTube().y);
        }
        sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
        sb.draw(ground,groundPos2.x,groundPos2.y);

        font24.draw(sb,SCORE,cam.position.x -2,cam.position.y + 15);
        sb.end();

    }

    /**
     * spritebatches must be drawn in order .The one at the bottommost acts as the top layer.
     */

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        actualGamebg.dispose();
        bird.dispose();
        font24.dispose();
        for(Tube tube: tubes)
        {
            tube.dispose();
        }
        ground.dispose();
        mainMusic.dispose();
        scoreIncrease.dispose();
        wingFlap.dispose();


        System.out.println("Play State Disposed");

    }




    private void updateGround()
    {
        if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos1.x + ground.getWidth())
        {
            groundPos1.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
        if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos2.x + ground.getWidth())
        {
            groundPos2.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
    }


    public void Score()
    {
        k++;
        scoreIncrease.play();
        scoreIncrease.setVolume(0.3f);

    }
    public int getL(){
        return l;
    }


    public void fontGenerator(){
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("bitmapfont/PressStart2P.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter= new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

        parameter.size=12;
        parameter.color= Color.GOLD;
        parameter.borderColor= Color.GOLDENROD;
        font24= generator.generateFont(parameter);
        font24.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
    }


    }
```

GameOverState:

```
 private Texture gameOver;
private Texture gameOverBg;
private Texture playAgainBtn;
private Texture ground;
private Vector2 groundPos1;
private Music gameOverMusic;
private BitmapFont totalScore;
private String STRING;
public PlayState playState;
public Boolean AdStart = true;




public GameOverState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, GrumpyDemo.WIDTH/2,GrumpyDemo.HEIGHT/2);

    gameOver = new Texture("gameover.png");
    gameOverBg =  new Texture ("bg.png");
    playAgainBtn = new Texture("playbtn.png");
    ground = new Texture("ground.png");
    AdStart = new Boolean(true);

    gameOverMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("gameoversfx.ogg"));
    groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x -cam.viewportWidth/2, -30);
    totalScore =  new BitmapFont();
    STRING = new String();
    playState = new PlayState(gsm);
    gameOverMusic.play();
    gameOverMusic.setVolume(1.0f);



}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
            gameOverMusic.stop();
            AdStart = false;

    }


}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    STRING = "SCORE: " + playState.getL();
    fontGenerator();

}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(gameOverBg,0,0);
    sb.draw(gameOver, cam.position.x-gameOver.getWidth()/2 , 5*(cam.position.y/3));
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(playAgainBtn,cam.position.x-playAgainBtn.getWidth()/2,2*(cam.position.y/3));
    totalScore.draw(sb,STRING,cam.position.x - gameOver.getWidth()/4 ,5*(cam.position.y/4));

    sb.end();


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    gameOver.dispose();
    gameOverBg.dispose();
    playAgainBtn.dispose();
    ground.dispose();
    totalScore.dispose();
    playState.dispose();

    System.out.println("Game Over State Disposed");

}

public void fontGenerator(){
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("bitmapfont/PressStart2P.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter= new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size=12;
    parameter.color= Color.GOLD;
    parameter.borderColor= Color.GOLDENROD;
    totalScore= generator.generateFont(parameter);
    totalScore.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
}

public Boolean getAdStart(){
    return AdStart;
}
```

Almost forgot it..My game state manager:

```
  package com.mygdx.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Created by Kronos on 28-01-2017.
 */

public class GameStateManager {

    private Stack<State> states;
    public GameStateManager(){

        states = new Stack<State>();
    }


    public void push(State state)
    {
        states.push(state);
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        states.pop().dispose();
    }

    public void set(State state)
    {
        states.pop().dispose();
        states.push(state);
    }

    public void update(float dt)
    {
        states.peek().update(dt);
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        states.peek().render(sb);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

(a) May be timer/counter is the reason for lagging, you can also use interestial Ad without it.

(b) where are you using AdStart Boolean of your GameOverState class.Call interestial ad only when your game move to GameOverState via using interface.

(c) create all your assets once and use it on different screen, dispose all assets when you exit your game.
dispose method of your Game is right place for dispose all of your assets.
It's better to use AssetManager for all your assets.